# TOTP intermittently does not return the same code when generated within the same time step

Tags: one-time-password

So we have the need for using a TOTP to generate a code on the server to send to a mobile client, I have been testing code generation with the following 3 java repos:

- https://github.com/jchambers/java-otp
- https://github.com/andOTP/andOTP
- https://github.com/freeotp/freeotp-android

I've taken the core TOTP generating code and I've been testing them. My issue is that I will run the arbitrary mvn unit test where using the default time step of 30 secs, I will generate a token (t0), wait 2 seconds, and generate another token (t1) and sometimes (like 1 of every 10 tries) t0 != t1. I can't figure out why this is and my math-fu is not at the level to fully grasp whether this is expected or whether I am doing something wrong.

Note that this happens for all the 3 code sources (i haven't changed the code except for providing the secret key) I mentioned above - clearly either i'm doing something wrong or this behavior is possibly expected?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the time step is 30 seconds, there is a 2/30 = 1/15 probability that your starting time will be a different time step from the ending time two seconds later.

Comment: i didn't get that, can you elaborate? Maybe I don't understand how TOTP works - if i generate a token at T0, i expect that (on the same machine) if i generate a token T1 two seconds after T0 and I have 30 seconds from the time i generated T0 to verify then T1 (which I generated 2 seconds after T0) should be the same and match.

Comment: To further explain my use case: i generate a token (T0) on the server, send it to a mobile device (via SMS), the device then calls the server with the token it received at which point the server will generate another token (T1) and if T0 == T1 then we authenticate the device. I assume this methodology is valid.

Comment: The timer doesn't start when you generate the token.  The timer starts on the epoch January 1, 1970, and the token is a function of the _number of full 30-second time steps since the epoch_.  About 1/15 of the time, if you wait two seconds between generating two tokens, you will cross one of those time step boundaries.

Comment: Ahhhh I got it, I was misunderstanding how TOTP works can I add a follow up to this @squeamish-ossifrage - why, in your opinion, is TOTP better than me generating a secure-random 6 digit token and managing the 30 sec life from that point onward, I will thereby eliminate the 1/15 probability. Certainly I'm not the first to think of doing this but still TOTP exists so there must be a reason why it is done rather than using a secure-random 6 digit token - maybe you can enlighten me (or should i follow protocol and post as a diff question)

Comment: How does the {client, server} know at which precise nanosecond the {server, client} generated its token in order to match that one, for the next thirty seconds?

Comment: Guess that's unavoidable, either approach has the same issue (that you pointed out) only diff the secure-random you at which point your 30 seconds (time step) starts but it's a probability in the case of TOTP.

Comment: @nonsequitor Forget security for a moment.  If you generate a TOTP from a nanosecond-resolution clock, how am I supposed to guess the exact moment, down to the nanosecond, at which you generated the TOTP?  At any given time with a 30sec time step, there are 30 _billion_ possible seeds that you could have used that are still valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78081/discussion-between-non-sequitor-and-squeamish-ossifrage).